# Помогите найти слово

Tags: общие-вопросы

Какое слово обозначает и предмет мебели и сборник стихотворений?

Answer (score 2):

Предмет мебели и сборник стихотворений- это диван.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это всё-таки слово "книжка",Vadimych74 прав, диван - для детей сложно, не каждый так начитан, а вот стол-книжка все знают, как и книжка стихов.

Answer (score 0):

Уточню: это диван-книжка, раскладывающийся. Кстати, "книжкой" бывает и складной стол.